# query to group remarks column with sum of other column in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

lets assume i have following table "marksheet":

```
userid | subject |  type     | marks | remarks
1        science    theory    35     good
1        science    practical 25     very good
1        computer  theory    50     very good
1        computer   practical 25     average
```

Now I want it like this:

```
userid  | subject | theory_marks | theory_remarks | practical_marks | practical_remarks
1        science     60              good              25                very good
1        computer    50              very good         15                average
```

I have tried this.

```
select userid, subject, sum(case when type = 'theory' then marks else 0) theory_marks, sum(case when type = 'practical' then marks else 0) practical_marks from marksheet group by userid, subject
```

Now, I want to add theory_remarks and practical_remarks as above (table2).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Use conditional aggregation to pivot more then one column at once. A lot of examples over there.

Comment: I am able to get the marks through sum but I am not able get the remarks for each type. If I try to use case to get remarks type, I will have to group them by 'type', which will create multiple rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `userid,subject,type` is unique

```
select userid, subject, 
   max(case when type = 'theory' then marks end) theory_marks, 
   max(case when type = 'practical' then marks end) practical_marks,
   max(case when type = 'theory' then remarks end) theory_remarks, 
   max(case when type = 'practical' then remarks end) practical_remarks    
from marksheet 
group by userid, subject
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems to get the result that I want. I didn't know I could use max() for text value too. Thank you for your help.